# Database issue in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry

i am developing application in blackberry and i m using eclipse.in my app there is a database.when i create database in 6.0 it work fine but in 5.0 database is not create. does any buddy have solution for problem plz send me.Thanx.

Comment: yes i getting Exception.

Comment: which exception can you tell us ????

Comment: invalid path name.path does not contains proper root file, see file system registry class for detail

Comment: that means you are not giving the right path can you post your some snippet of your code. Are you `simulating the SDCard` and are you craeting the Database on SDCard or in the phone memory ???

Comment: in comments i can not send more text.from where i cn send code ?

Comment: you can edit your question nad put some snippet of your code

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5579/discussion-between-hasmukh-bhadani-and-bbdev)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you can do is to Checking for the `SDCard`. I think you are not Mounting  the SDCard in your simulator. So mount the SDCard in your simulator you can do this As stated below.

From simulator SelectThe `simulate option -> selectChangeSDCard -> from popup AddDirectory and then close` . Now you can see your database folder in the simulator.